# Sending an SMS through SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sms

Is there any way to send an SMS through SQL Server 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not a feature of SQL Server.

Comment: That is cruel considering alternatives available, as per the answers below

Answer (score 4):

One possible option is to use an SMS gateway like the [Clickatell API](http://www.clickatell.com/products/sms%5Fgateway.php).

The Clickatell API offers a choice of connection options, including an SMTP method which you can use by sending a plain-text email from SQL Server to `sms@messaging.clickatell.com`, with the following body:

```
user:     your_api_username
password: your_api_password
api_id:   your_api_id
to:       sms_number
text:     sms_body
```

To send e-mails from SQL Server 2008, you might want to check out the following article:

- [Configure Database Mail – Send Email From SQL Database](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/).

Another option is to write a CLR stored procedure that communicates with the SMS gateway through any protocol supported by the gateway.

Answer (score 4):

Each phone carrier have email addresses that will forward to the sms/text of their subscribers and you just have send an email to these addresses and recipient will receive the messages thru sms.

example. 8009994141@phonecarrier.com

This is a link to a page to most of the carriers email to text format. Please note that this might contain not the latest information.

The best way is to call the technical support for your carrier get the information and test the feature by emailing and see if you get an sms message/

Comment: I got this to work very easily using database mail and an "email addess" of 123456789@txt.att.net to send myself text messages.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, although not natively. You will have to use an SMS gateway service and do some programming around it. These come in several formats, occasionally free, but normally with some form of per message charge.

Standard gateways will accept message requests via email, a web post, or a full web service. Depending on the gateway service it may offer one, some, or all of these options.

Back in the "olden days" when I mobile SMS started to take off, in the UK at least, it was also possible to use a dial up modem to dial a network specific number and enter the SMS message. If this is still available in the area that you are looking for then the advantage of this is no account setup as it's charged to your phone bill.

Comment: Or use a GSM modem (or these days just about any mobile phone with bluetooth).

But you still need some software to bridge the database to the device driver.

C.

Comment: Ah yes, I was so deep in old-man-land that I forgot about GSM terminals, mobiles with a data cable, mobiles with bluetooth, or mobile broadband dongles. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I found an article which uses c# application with a SQL Server Backend to send SMS emails. Not exactly what your after but may give you another option.

[SMS messages from SQL](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SMS_message_from_SQL.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

How about an option that lets you do this in one line of code.

[twiSQL - allows you to send text messages and make phone calls from SQL server](http://www.twilio.com/gallery/projects/twiSQL)

[austinHenderson.com - author site](http://www.austinhenderson.com/Projects/twiSQL.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be to write a CLR procedure that sends the sms via http to a SMS gateway of your choice

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to nornal's answer since the link he spoke about seemes to have expired:

```
Alltel  PhoneNumber@message.alltel.com
AT&T    PhoneNumber@txt.att.net
Sprint  PhoneNumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com
T-Mobile    PhoneNumber@tmomail.net
US Cellular PhoneNumber@email.uscc.net
Verizon PhoneNumber@vtext.com
Virgin Mobile   PhoneNumber@vmobl.com
```

So Ex: 3334441234@txt.att.net. 
You use the above according to the provider.